# How to retrieve the result of the SQLite3 C based SELECT Query as JSON?

Tags: c++, sqlite

Im trying to get the output of the SELECT query into a JSON file.
Is there a function available in SQLite C interface?

Otherwise i have to iterate the callback function of the `sqlite_exec()` for each row, right?

```
int sqlite3_exec(
  sqlite3*,                                  /* An open database */
  const char *sql,                           /* SQL to be evaluated */
  int (*callback)(void*,int,char**,char**),  /* Callback function */
  void *,                                    /* 1st argument to callback */
  char **errmsg                              /* Error msg written here */
);
```

is there an more efficient way to directly access the stored column data?
something like: array[] xy = sqlite_get_table() ?

Comment: Use a [prepared statement](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html), not `sqlite3_exec()`, when you want to do something with the results of a query.

Comment: thank you! i combined now the json query with the prepared_stmt. exactely what i looked for!

Answer (score 2):

If your build of SQLite has the optional [json1](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) extension, SQLite can summarize an entire table or subquery into a single JSON string on its own:

```sql
create table sandwiches (name, price);
insert into sandwiches values ('cheese', 1);
insert into sandwiches values ('ham', 2);

select json_group_array(json_array(name, price)) from sandwiches;
-- gives you: [["cheese",1],["ham",2]]

select json_group_array(json_object('name', name, 'price', price)) from sandwiches;
-- gives you: [{"name":"cheese","price":1},{"name":"ham","price":2}]
```

Both those queries have *one* row and *one* column as their result, which means that something like...

```cpp
sqlite3_exec(db, "select …", +[](void*, int, char** values, char**) {
    /* values[0] contains a null-terminated C string filled with JSON */
    return 0;
}, nullptr, nullptr);
```

...or the equivalent `sqlite3_prepare`, `sqlite3_step`, `sqlite3_finalize` should then do the trick.

Comment: thanks for the hint. i still tried to json_group it before, but it returns an error that its not available. i guess its not included in the C library.

Comment: If you're sure the extension is not in there, you can add it by defining the SQLITE_ENABLE_JSON1 macro when you build SQLite: https://sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_json1